# Matlab-generated Dll in C

Tags: c, matlab, dll, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder

I created a dll of a simple function in Matlab using this command:

```
mcc -t -L C -W lib:testfunctionLib -T link:lib testfunction.m libmmfile.mlib
```

The simple function looks like:

```
function y = testfunction(x) 
y = x + 10;
end
```

I need to call the dll via c-code. This is what i'm using to get the result of the computation with the dll-function into a textfile:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int z = 1;
    FILE *Testfile;

    typedef int(*BinaryFunction_t) (int);
    BinaryFunction_t  AddNumbers;
    int            result;
    BOOL              fFreeResult;
    HINSTANCE         hinstLib = LoadLibraryA("testfunctionLib.dll");

if (hinstLib != NULL)
    {
    AddNumbers = (BinaryFunction_t)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "testfunction");

    if (AddNumbers != NULL)
        result = (*AddNumbers) (z);

    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);

    Testfile = fopen("Testfile.txt", "a");
    fprintf(Testfile, "%i\n", result);
    fclose(Testfile);
    }
else
    {
    Testfile = fopen("Testfile.txt", "a");
    fprintf(Testfile, "NOT");
    fclose(Testfile);
    }
}
```

I always get a 'NOT' in my textfile because the c-code can't extract the function out of the dll. Why doesn't this work? The c-code for getting the dll-function should be ok, i tested it with a dll created within visual studio.

Comment: You have failed to load your library. Check what's going wrong with `GetLastError`

Comment: Note: `mcc` is part of the MATLAB Compiler, which is for deploying MATLAB applications to end-user who don't have access to MATLAB. However, it requires the end-user to install the MCR (MATLAB Component Runtime) on his/her machine, which is freely distributable if you have a license of MATLAB Compiler. If you want truly standalone C code, you should be using MATLAB Coder instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you need to manually dynamically load the library? Could you instead just link against the library and include the generated headers?

Comment: Try it without the .dll.  I'm not sure about c, but in java it prepends lib and adds the .so suffex, and for dll's just adds the dll suffix.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the library failed to load, but i don't receive any error message.. I also tried to build the dll by the Matlab Coder. I get i lot of different files (c,h,etc) and a single dll-file called testfunction. But including this dll is still not working..

Comment: This really isn't an answer and should likely be a comment to follow up on what am304 said.